# Jenkins v1.563 Legacy

Tags: jenkins

Yes, I know, but we have a legacy Jenkins server running Ubuntu 08.04, and I tried to upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu, but then I broke the whole system, I would like to confirm the following:

1. What java version does Jenkins 1.5 use?
2. What PostgreSQL does Jenkins 1.5 use?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its is Ubutu 18.04, right ? Also have you not taken the snapshot of the server ?

Comment: Based on [this commit](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/commit/3431a7cba), seems last Jenkins on 1.5 was < 1.563.

Comment: @error404 nope, its 08.04 and yes I did but still fails.

Answer (score 0):

[Cloudbees](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360020783632-Java-compatibility-Apache-Maven-and-Jenkins-Best-Practices) has the following info:

> - Jenkins >= 1.520 (1.532.1 for LTS) requires Java 6 thus Maven jobs    must be launched with a JDK >= 6.
> - Jenkins >= 1.612 (1.625.1 for LTS) requires Java 7 thus Maven jobs    must be launched with a JDK >= 7.
> - Jenkins >= 2.54 (2.60.1 for LTS) requires Java 8 thus Maven jobs must    be launched with a JDK >= 8.

Comment: @quentin. Thx for markup fix; my mobile browser does not provide the editor toolbar or a preview and the copy / paste dropped the bullets and took indent as code!